# Sum of rows of two individual columns in mssql table and get result on individual basis

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table for purchase invoice. I want to get total of all the invoices as well as the total of paid against each invoice. I have run query in mssql and its woring fine.

`

```
string query = "select sum(Total),sum(AmountPaid) from PurchaseInvoice where SupplierId=" + dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();
double totalAmount = double.Parse(rdr[0].ToString());
double AmountPaid = double.Parse(rdr[1].ToString());
con.Close();
```

`

Now when i execute it I get exception at reading record 
**"Input string was not in correct format."**

Actually i can understand that data is not coming from database. Please suggest some approporiate method to read data.

Comment: If the query is working fine, what is your question?

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for the misconvinience

Comment: it returns empty string

Comment: both the values of sum are empty string

Comment: ok. so problem is somewhere else. i thought maybe its because of culture info

Comment: I ran query in sql server and it is executes perfectly

Comment: Print the values of `rdr[0]` and `rdr[1]` before parsing them, and see what's wrong.

Comment: i printed them and these are empty strings

Comment: My inclination would be to think that something is wrong with dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString(). Print out the value of the 'query' variable.

Answer (score 0):

SUM - Returns the sum of all the values, or only the DISTINCT values, in the expression. SUM can be used with numeric columns only. Null values are ignored. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190349%28v=sql.120%29.aspx